# Animate lines to move towards the screen / user | Create a "tunnel effect"

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

**This question is of both designing and programming nature, as i have two parts of a problem which address these areas. I posted it here because i want to create a animation i JS that i do neither know how to display nor animate!** If you think this question is in the wrong place, or you require any additional information, please let me know.

I'm having quite some trouble imagining on how to create a effect that creates the feeling of "being in a endless tunnel" or "falling down a pipe" which is done by generating "lines that move towards the screen" both circular and linear. I have seen some videos that create exactly this effect, but i have no idea on how to recreate this in JavaScript.

For a visual example please see this [video](https://www.shutterstock.com/de/video/clip-7524109-stock-footage-flight-in-abstract-futuristic-tunnel-d-animation.html?src=search/89bKf1euPGpi8I4UL-3cGg:1:46/3p).

I am quite new to these bit more complex animations, i have tried solving this issue with scaling and moving canvas elements via keyframes / transitions + css mainupluation (*that's my usual way to solve simple animations like moving or fading elements etc.*) already but can't wrap my head around on how i have to resize or move my content to make it look like in the video, i just cannot figure out which properties get changed that it looks like that.

In the video you can see the circular shapes and the linear shapes, i can imagine i can easily scale up the circular ones and so create the illusion of them moving towards the screen, which would be no problem but i simply have no idea how the linear ones work.

I tried playing around with drawing in a canvas and animating the drawn lines, and it looks promising but as said have no concrete idea.

I would appreciate any tips in the right direction or any approaches on what to animate to create this effect.

Comment: This is a programming QA website. You usually come here to ask about specifics once you have already tried something. Try some other forum or read a little bit more about JS animation first.

Comment: Hello Josep, thank you for your feedback! As i see you think the problem does not fit in here as i wish it could. My problem is, i fail at trying to imagine what properties i would have to animate to create the effect. E.g. if i would have the information i have to draw in a canvas, then resize it in a given manner and move it in some direction, that would be no problem. I am feeling a little helpless because finding a solution is very hard for me, i surely did try to search in other places but found nothing that fits.

Comment: There are multiple possible approaches but from your response you are mixing a canvas approach where you draw things to (circles and lines) to a SVG/CSS approach where you have objects with properties you animate. And if you are talking about a 3D effect, there is the whole WebGL stuff too.

Comment: Hi again Joseph, i assume i couldn't communicate my problem properly, so i asked a friend of mine for help. Everything fixed with canvas manipulation, what i was missing was the knowledge this effect is created by spawning lines in some angle and as they move farther out change their length and speed they move out. Case closed.

Comment: Refer to the second example in my answer below then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your response to my comment I believe you are confusing concepts and technologies. First set for one approach and then read a little bit more on how it works.

If you want to use **CSS/SVG** where you **animate properties**, take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zungoro/zr6Dd/

If you want use an HTML5 **canvas** you need to **draw** (primitives such as lines and circles), these are a nice examples of what can be accomplished: http://www.chiptune.com/starfield/starfield.html and http://js1k.com/2013-spring/demo/1443

You can use **WebGL** if you want **realistic 3D**, see these examples: http://jeromeetienne.github.io/tunnelgl/ (tutorial here http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/11/tunnel-effect/ ) and http://www.brainjam.ca/stackoverflow/webglspiral.html

`enter code hereStackoverrflow doesn't let me link to JSfiddle w/o code.`

Comment: Thank you for your time Josep, the example on chiptune is pretty similar to what we created! I'll accept this as the right answer as i see you understood what i wanted to know, just a little after i finished it myself with help!